# How to display ACF relation field using Post Grid in WPBakery Page builder

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I would like to display a Post Grid in a post.

The post contains an ACF field, field type is set to 'relationship' and return format is set to 'Post Objects'. So essencially. I'm trying to get Post Grid to display 'Post Objects' stored in this ACF field.

However, Post Grid does not seem to provide this capability (It only allows me to choose post from specific categories etc.).

I want to take the advantage of Post Grid because of it flexibility and rich layouts, however, it seems it is not able to understand the current page context and display posts based on current post.